# React responsive nav component es6 function not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not quite sure why the click event is not working.
I simply trying the use a responsive accessible navigation but looks like I'm missing something in the constructor or I'm not firing the function properly?
I have the feeling that my es6 constructor is not right.
Please let me know if you could help me

```js
import React, { Component} from "react";
import {hot} from "react-hot-loader";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "../styles/navbar.scss"
import cart from '../assets/images/cart.png'


class NavBar extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.responsiveNav = this.responsiveNav.bind(this);
  
  }
responsiveNav(){
  const primaryNav = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
  const navToggle = document.querySelector(".mobile-nav-toggle");
  
  navToggle.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log('click')
    const visibility = primaryNav.getAttribute("data-visible");
  
    if (visibility === "false") {
      primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", true);
      navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", true);
    } else if (visibility === "true") {
      primaryNav.setAttribute("data-visible", false);
      navToggle.setAttribute("aria-expanded", false);
    }
  });
  
  }

 

  render(){
    return(
      <div id={this.props.id} className="navbar">
        

        <button  className="mobile-nav-toggle" aria-controls="nav-items" aria-expanded="false">
        <span className="sr-only">Menu</span>
        </button>
        <nav className="nav">
          <div className="nav-menu flex-row">
            <div className="nav-brand">
                <h2><Link to="/">APP</Link></h2>
            </div>

            <ul className="menu" data-visible="false" className="primary-nav flex">
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Products</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">News</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/">Content</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <Link to="/cart"><img src={cart} alt="cart icon"/><div id="yourcart">Your Cart</div></Link>
                </li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

export default hot(module)(NavBar);
```

Comment: you are only defined the `responsiveNav` not calling from anywhere.
also why you are mixing up normal js and react js. use onClick attribute and add your function there. just go through the react docs first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few things going on here. First, use state to manage `visible`. Your use of the `data` attribute makes it look like you're coming from a jQuery like background, and things are done a little differently in React. Second, modern React development uses function components over classes. Classes are still supported, for backwards compatibility, but will eventually go away.

I don't know about your stylesheet, but I'm guessing it's triggering off your `aria-expanded` attribute to determine if the menu is truly shown via CSS. That being the case, your `NavBar` becomes something like this.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

import "../styles/navbar.scss";
import cart from "../assets/images/cart.png";

export default function NavBar() {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const onClick = () => setVisible((prev) => !prev);

  return (
    <div id={this.props.id} className="navbar">
      <button
        id="menucontrol"
        className="mobile-nav-toggle"
        aria-haspopup="menu"
        aria-controls="nav-items"
        aria-expanded={visible}
        onClick={onClick}
      >
        <span className="sr-only">Menu</span>
      </button>
      <nav className="nav">
        <div className="nav-menu flex-row">
          <div className="nav-brand">
            <h2>
              <Link to="/">APP</Link>
            </h2>
          </div>

          <ul
            className="menu primary-nav flex"
            id="nav-items"
            aria-expanded={visible}
            aria-labelledby="menucontrol"
          >
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Products</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">News</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Content</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/cart">
                <img src={cart} alt="cart icon" />
                <div id="yourcart">Your Cart</div>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can see here that I've defaulted it's visibility to `false`, and toggle it's state on button click (I'm guessing your routing change will remove the menu all together, or you'd have to toggle on route change as well). I've also expanded your `aria` code to mirror the [W3C example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/WD-wai-aria-practices-1.1-20161214/examples/menu-button/menu-button-1/menu-button-1.html) of this type of component.

This isn't using your hot module reloader only because I'm unfamiliar with it's usage in production.